# Visual Studio debugger - Displaying integer values in Binary

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, binary, integer

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and I need to look at the binary representation of integer variables.

How can this be achieved from the Visual Studio debugger?

[image: Visual Studio Watch Window]

Comment: It is already displayed in binary, hex is a nice compact representation.  0 = 0000, 1 = 0001, ... E = 1110, F = 1111.  So this is 01010000000000000000000000000000.  Or copy-paste the value into the calculator, switched to Programmer mode  Ought to be enough digits to convince you that you need binary notation a lot less than you thought.

Answer (score 21):

Type 'var, b' in the watch, for example:

[image]

Comment: seems like it doesn't work (VisualStudio 2019 Professional)

Comment: @GiacomoPirinoli Strange, it works fine in Visual Studio Community 2019.

Answer (score 5):

According to the Visual Studio debugger [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/format-specifiers-in-cpp?view=vs-2019):

> You can change the format in which a value is displayed in the Watch, Autos, and Locals windows by using **format specifiers**.

This note on **debugging engine updates** and **compatibility** is also worth noting:

> When the Visual Studio native debugger changed to a new debugging engine, some new format specifiers were added and some old ones were removed. The older debugger is still used when you do interop (mixed native and managed) debugging with C++/CLI.

Although it mentions it can be applied to `Autos` and `Locals` windows, it is unclear how it is done as the variable names cannot be edited in those windows.

A `<variable>, <format>` syntax may be used in `Watch` and `Immediate` windows, like so:

[image]

Here is a direct link to the complete list of [format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/format-specifiers-in-cpp?view=vs-2019#BKMK_Visual_Studio_2012_format_specifiers).

Comment: Obviously does'nt work for C# code.. :-(

Answer (score 2):

Right-click the value  it’ll show a menu list, but it only give us the option of Hexadecimal Display. 
To display the variable with binary value in watch window,  I suggest you  write function to covert it :

[image]

The function that in my code is:

```
public static string ToBinaryString(uint num)
    {
        return Convert.ToString(num, 2).PadLeft(32, '0');
    }
```

Comment: @Stepan Ivanenko, Would you please share us the latest information in your side?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an extension method `Binary()` and then use the Watch window to call it on whatever variable I want to see.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string Binary(this byte inputByte)
    {
        return $"{Convert.ToString(inputByte, toBase: 2).PadLeft(8, '0')}";
    }
}
```

Screenshot showing it in action in VSCode (should work in Visual Studio, too):

[image: VSCode screenshot showing Binary() extension method in action]